# Angular - Failed to instantiate module materialism module materialism is unavailable after calling $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Materialism is the name of the app as defined in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('materialism', [
```

The problem:

[image: The problem]

My [files](https://gist.github.com/MichaelArnoldOwens/3bbba6244ab26b82d532). If I refresh the page in browser after routing, I do not get any errors. I'm stuck. I have no idea why materialism app is not be instantiated. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You forgot to include `app.js ` in your `index.html`

Comment: it is included in my build file that includes all script dependecies

Comment: Post your html file so we can troubleshoot...

Answer (score 0):

In my node server file dashboard_server, in my /storeBilling endpoint, I was using node to redirect with res.redirect() so it was going out of angular scope.